# Inline return false stopping my setTimeout

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have following code which captures when a user clicks on the a tag in the li. I can successfully capture the event, but if I use setTimeout in the event the inline 'return false' in the a tag stops this from happening. Any ideas on how to stop or remove the inline a tag 'return false;'?

I cannot just delete it as this is being used for the desktop site and I am overriding its functionality for the mobile site.

```
<ul class="paginate">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://www.xxx.co.uk/xxx/" onclick="ajaxPage('2',true,'left'); return false;">2</a>
 </li>
</ul>

$('.paginate li a').click(function(){ 
 alert('Caught page'); // THIS WORKS
 setTimeout(function(){
    setSearchPrice(); // THIS DOESN'T WORK, GET SUPPRESSED BUT THE INLINE RETURN FALSE
 },1400)
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's even technically impossible. If `alert` works, then so does `setTimeout` because JavaScript is singlethreaded ( unless you use some weird implementation ). There must be something wrong with your `setSearchPrice` function.

Comment: _"I cannot just delete it"_ - Sure you can. Adapt your jQuery-based `.click()` handler accordingly. Further to what @freakish said, try temporarily putting the alert inside the timeout function instead of `setSearchPrice()` and see what happens.

Comment: I placed the alert at the top of the setSearchPrice method, but it doesn't trigger (I call this method elsewhere and it works fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot just delete it as this is being used for the desktop site and I am overriding its functionality for the mobile site.

I don't see what that has to do with it, but you can remove the `onclick` DOM0 handler:

```
$('.paginate li a').each(function() {
  // Remove the onclick set up in the markup, since you're replacing it
  this.onclick = null;
}).click(function(e){ 
 // The replacement
 alert('Caught page');
 setTimeout(function(){
    setSearchPrice();
 },1400)
 // Probably want to prevent the default, since you've removed
 // the `return false` on the DOM0 handler that used to do it
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest the use of `event.preventDefault()`;
It will stop the default action of the event.
Here is a good explanation how it works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault

Comment: The `return false;` in the DOM0 `onclick` handler is already preventing the default.

Comment: Its not preventing the default. Its stopping the whole event.
Here is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BGY5b/

Comment: @ Digvijay: Your example doesn't have the `return false` in the DOM0 handler. See my comment above: `return false` in a DOM0 handler prevents the default action (and *doesn't* stop propagation or other handlers). [More here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html), and [demonstration here](http://jsbin.com/esesuv/1).

Comment: As far as I can understand the question, the user does not want to go to the link in the a tag. He just want to call the ajax function, which my example does. So there is no need to use the return statement.

Comment: Also if you want the return statement, you can put it in the inline tag.

Comment: @ Digvijay: You're missing the point. Your answer says "use `preventDefault`". He's **already** preventing the default. So the answer isn't useful.

Comment: Yes he is preventing the default action, but also the user action, that should be called after the return.

Comment: @ Digvijay: No. ***Again***: `return false` doesn't stop propagation, and doesn't prevent other handlers getting called (as I demonstrated).